# Suitable Regex for finding value to a key in yaml file

Tags: regex, inspec

I want to make sure that I am using aescbc as provider.

```
kind: EncryptionConfig
apiVersion: v1
resources:
  - resources:
    - secrets
    providers:
    - aescbc:
        keys:
        - name: key1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess,

```
\bproviders:\s*-\s*\baescbc:
```

might simply suffice on `s` mode.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bwqPel/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/bwqPel/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---